# Finding the maximum number of id's among all weeks available

Tags: python

this is a really short code, but I'm trying to improve my Python skills. I've got a DataFrame, with a `week` variable, for every week I want to know the number of different `id`'s in that week, and then get the maximum number of id's among all weeks. I achieve that doing this:

```
listt=[]
for i in range(df.week.max()):
    listt.append(df[df.week==i].id.nunique())
np.array(listt).max()
```

It feels to me that this can probably be done in a one-liner. How would you do it? Thanks

Comment: Thanks @MathiasEttinger, should have read that before posting. Is the title okay right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through each possible week and filtering your dataframe, you should use [`df.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and work from there using convenience methods on the results:

```
df.groupby('week').id.nunique().max()
```

Comment: I knew it could be done way easily. Thanks again, Mathias